# problem in markerclusterer.js

Tags: google-maps

i have an problem and error when include markerclusterer.js in my code..
when i run the program, the error below shown:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'GOverlay' is undefined
the error code is ClusterMarker_.prototype = new GOverlay();

it is happen on markerclusterer.js...
please help me if u know the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the markerclusterer.js file after the main google maps include with your key? The map gmaps2 lib needs to be loaded first.

Comment: yes..i included the markerclusterer.js file after the main google maps with key..but the problem still there..